# Regex - International Password Match Expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to compose a pattern which matches passwords in any language.

The matcher requirement is :-

- 1 Upper Char (Min)
- 1 Lower Char (Min)
- 1 Digit (Min)
- 1 Symbol (Min)
- 8 Characters length or above

As i'm sure you can see from my pattern below, I'm lost!!

`/^(?=.*[\p{Ll}])(?=.*[\p{Lu}])(?=.*\p{Nd})(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\p{Nd}$@$!%*?&]{8,}$/u`

Test strings

1. 关键字157aA$89
2. P455word123!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\p{Lu}` matches uppercase Unicode letters, and `\p{Ll}` matches lowercase Unicode letters. Chinese letters are caseless, they can be matched with `\p{L}` (together with all other letters).

Use `\p{L}` in the consuming part:

```
/^(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Nd})(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[\p{L}\p{Nd}@$!%*?&]{8,}$/u
                                                      ^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QUbSjz/1).

Note that a password will still have to have an uppercase and lowercase letters. If you just want to require a Chinese letter or an uppercase with lowercase letters, use

```
/^(?:(?=.*\p{Han})|(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu}))(?=.*\p{Nd})(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[\p{L}\p{Nd}$@!%*?&]{8,}$/u
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here, `(?:(?=.*\p{Han})|(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu}))` will require either a Chinese letter (`\p{Han}`) or an uppercase+lowercase letter.